# Custom subdomain for github pages

Tags: html, github, dns, hosting, github-pages

I want to host a website with github pages and as I understood, the domain to my website will be `myusername.github.io` but what if I want something like `custom.github.io` do I need to create another github account? Or I can change that without buying a custom domain?

Comment: The subdomain comes from your org so you can't just change that in a setting but have to create a new org with that namespace. More infos here: https://docs.github.com/en/pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create another account for that, you can directly change the name of the repository to `custom.github.io` instead of `repository`.

As: if your repository name is `example` then your site is hosted at `myusername.github.io/example` but if you want the site to hosted at `custom.github.io` instead of `myusername.github.io/example` then type the whole custom repository link, i.e. `custom.github.io` in the name of the repository instead of `example`, then your site will be hosted at `custom.github.io` (if it is available).